# How to sort a Reporting Services table by an auto generated column

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

I have this table:

[image]

When executed, it looks like:

[image]

This table is sorted by alphabetical order. I would like to sort it by the column named "No Vencido", which is generated in runtime combining 2 dimensions of a cube (one dimension is called "Class 1", the other dimension is called "value".

How can i sort a table by an autogenerated field?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by any sort of expression - SSRS will quite happily sort something like two fields concatenated together:

```
=Fields!Class1.Value & Fields!value.Value
```

Just be careful to make sure the sorting is applied at the appropriate level to avoid unexpected, i.e. make sure you don't have different sorting expressions in any row group or detail group if not required.

If **No Vencido** is the grouping expression, apply the sorting at the group level.

If you don't want to sort on an expression, you can create a calculated field for each row in the dataset with the expression `=Fields!Class1.Value & Fields!value.Value` and group/sort on that calculated field as required.

**Edit after comment**

OK, I think you need to apply a sort expression like this to the groups that apply to the `Top` and `Otros` rows:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!Clase_1.Value = "No Vencido", Fields!Monto.Value, Nothing))
```

This is still sorting by the total `Monto` for each row group, but only considering the rows where `Clase_1` is **No Vencido**.

Once this is set up sort by **A-Z** or **Z-A** as required.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I updated the image I uploaded. My problem is I don't understand how to choose to sort by "No Vencido" and not by "Vencido". These two are te values than Clase_1 can get.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the new info. I think I see the specific requirement now - please see updated answer.